# Updating href does not change where the link takes me

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, href

I am building a chrome extension to update all of the hrefs in a page to call a phone number (phone_number) instead of link to a page (/phone/phone_number) with the phone number listed again... I'm testing right now by hard coding the phone number that will be click-to-called. Unfortunately, even after updating the href, the link still takes me to the original page "/phone/phone_number", and does not trigger the call alert dialog on chrome.

```
window.onload = async () => {
  await sleep(3000);
  var phone_blocks = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("px-5 py-7 pearl td-n card flat"))

  phone_blocks.forEach(block => {
    block.href = "tel:8607817749"
  });

}
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

As you can see below, the href is changed per the console, but when I click it, I'm directed to the page that the href originally linked to - not the phone-number. If I right click and "copy link address", then I receive "tel:+18607817749" in my clipboard. Why is clicking it taking me to the old link?

[image]

Comment: I can't think of any reason other than you're clicking before 3 seconds. Why are you delaying 3 seconds for this?

Comment: Another reason may be that the page has its own click listener that uses the original URL internally. You can override the click: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58606030).

Comment: @Barmar I am definitely not clicking before 3 seconds. I'm delaying 3s because the page seems to do a bit of a hiccup 50% of the time after it's first load and the href will change and then revert. I tried that and that didn't work. Is there any way I could check in the inspect panel if that is happening?

Comment: When I hover over the link in the inspect panel @wOxxOm, it shows the original url. As if tel:phone_number actually links to the original url...

Comment: If I right click and open link in a new tab, it will call the number...

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.